# Scala Tail recursion future returns

Tags: scala, future, tail-recursion

how to implement a tail recursion functions in scala with futures as return values:

**Example code**

```
 def getInfo(lists: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = {
  def getStudentIDs(lists: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = {
    //here a web service call that returns a future WS response
        val response=ws.call(someURL)

        response.map(r => {
          r.status match {

            case 200 =>
              var newList = lists + (r.json \ ids)
                .as[List[Int]] //here add the ws call response json..
              getStudentIDs(newList)
            case 429 =>Future.sucessful(lists)
            case _ => getStudentIDs(lists)
          }

        })
      }
      getStudentIDs(List.empty[Int])
    }
```

Comment: I think the only way to return a `Future` from a tail recursive method is if the `Future` is only created at the terminus (i.e. final iteration). If the `Future(result)` is passed through the call stack unchanged then the method is tail recursive. If, as in your example, each iteration creates a fresh `Future` then those will have to be flattened as they are returned through the call stack, which precludes tail recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's an XY-problem. You probably don't want it "tail-recursive" in the sense of "having a @tailrec"-annotation. What you want is *stack safety*, so that this method does not blow the stack after a few hundred retries to connect to your webservice.

For this, there are libraries, for example [Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/).

In Cats, there is a typeclass called [`Monad`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Monad.html), and this typeclass provides a special method for what seems to be exactly what you want:

```
 tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: (A) => F[Either[A, B]]): F[B]
```

Quote from the docs:

> Keeps calling f until a scala.util.Right[B] is returned.
>   Implementations of this method should use constant stack space [...]

There is an implementation of this for `Future` [in `FutureInstances`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/instances/FutureInstances.html) available. The implementation seems trivial though, because it mixes in [`StackSafeMonad`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/StackSafeMonad.html).

You could of course look into implementation of `StackSafeMonad`, and then try to understand why it is sufficient in the case of `Future`, but you could also just use the library implementation instead and not worry about whether your recursive method can fail with a `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem (code simplified to make it runnable):

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import annotation.tailrec   
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

 def getInfo(lists: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = {
  @tailrec
  def getStudentIDs(lists: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = {
     Future(List(1, 2, 3)).flatMap(x => getStudentIDs(x ::: lists))
  }
     getStudentIDs(List.empty[Int])
  }
```

Gives an error:

```
error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method getStudentIDs: 
it contains a recursive call not in tail position
            Future(1).flatMap(x => getStudentIDs(x :: lists))
                      ^
```

The problem is not only with a `Future`. The actual problem is that  `getStudents` is not in terminal/tail position - it's called from `map`. This would be a problem if you use no Futures and use regular `map` from collections or any other function for that matter. For example:

```
 def getInfo(lists: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  @tailrec
  def getStudentIDs(lists: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
     List(1).flatMap(x => getStudentIDs(x :: lists))
  }
     getStudentIDs(List.empty[Int])
  }
```

Gives the same error:

```
error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method getStudentIDs:
it contains a recursive call not in tail position
            List(1).flatMap(x => getStudentIDs(x :: lists))
                    ^
```

What makes it difficult here is that you can't just get a result from future directly to use it in `getStudents` because you don't know if it's completed and it's not a good practice to block on Future and await for result. So you sort of forced to use `map`. Here is a very bad example of how to make it tail recursive (just for science :)). Don't do it in production code:

```
 def getInfo(lists: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = {
  @tailrec
  def getStudentIDs(lists: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = {
     val r = Await.ready(Future(List(1, 2, 3)), Duration.Inf).value.get.getOrElse(lists)
     getStudentIDs(r ::: lists)
  }
     getStudentIDs(List.empty[Int])
  }
```

The compiler is happy, but this might lead to many problems - read about `Await`, `blocking` and thread pools for more on that.

I think it's probably not a big issue that your function is not tail recursive because you probably don't want to create lots of futures this way anyway. There are other concurrency frameworks you could try if that's really a problem like actors (Akka), etc.

Comment: Hi thank you for the explanation.is there any way to achieve without using `Await`

Comment: You can't do tail recursion like I've explained but other options are possible like suggestion from @Andrey Tyukin. You can also create a `Promise` and get an uncompleted future out of it: `p.future`. Return this future back to the caller while in your web api function you can keep looping and getting a future response - install onComplete callback to check if you got enough data, if not, keep making new calls. Otherwise when done complete that promise.

Comment: See this blog post: http://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-9.html